# Finding coherent groups of identical items in pandas dataframe across one dimension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have following pandas dataframe containing US GDP data. Column `Change` holds absolute change values from quarter to quarter and column `Trend` is just a gimmick to make trend changes more visible.

```
             GDP  Change Trend
Quarter                       

2007q4   14991.8    53.3    up
2008q1   14889.5  -102.3  down
2008q2   14963.4    73.9    up
2008q3   14891.6   -71.8  down
2008q4   14577.0  -314.6  down
2009q1   14375.0  -202.0  down
2009q2   14355.6   -19.4  down
2009q3   14402.5    46.9    up
2009q4   14541.9   139.4    up
2010q1   14604.8    62.9    up
```

What I want to achieve is to find the quarter in which a recession began. A recession is defined by 2 consecutive quarterly decreases in GDP. I am sure that this task can be solved by iterating over rows but I am wondering if there is a more pandorable, vectorised way. I have tried a couple of things using `df.rolling()` but I cannot seem to find a way. Help is much appreciated!

Edit: In the example above the start of a recession would be 2008q3. Sorry for that ambiguity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
((df['Change'].shift() < 0) &(df['Change'].shift(2) < 0)).idxmax()
```

You get

```
'2009q1'
```

For the Edit, just a little tweak to the condition

```
((df['Change'] < 0) &(df['Change'].shift(-1) < 0)).idxmax()
```

And you get

```
'2008q3'
```

Comment: Thank you! I made an edit on my question to specify what result I want to obtain.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying shift but couldn't see the solution :)

Comment: Great that it worked for you and thank you for accepting :)

Comment: For what it's worth, if you wanted to do this using the Trend column, you could use .diff() instead of .shift()

Comment: Looks like subtraction doesn't work on strings `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` :)

Comment: Can you print df.dtypes and post here?

Comment: If the change column is of type string, first convert it to floats using df['Change'] = df['Change'].astype('float64')

Comment: No worries, I was referring to ZaxR and his proposition to apply `df['Trend'].diff()`!

Comment: @neurotronix, oh got it. I thought you got the error with my solution:)

Answer (score 2):

Use `shift` :

```
df['Trend2']=df['Trend'].shift(-1)
df['recession']= np.logical_and(df.Trend=='down',df.Trend2=='down')

2007q4    False
2008q1    False
2008q2    False
2008q3     True
2008q4     True
2009q1     True
2009q2    False
2009q3    False
2009q4    False
2010q1    False
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I had shift on my mind. But check out the edit on my answer please.

Comment: Oh my, I was so close but could not see it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I accepted the other answer over yours only because it is a one-liner!